# Get old search style back in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 14.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 and I love the new update and everything, but I miss the old search method. Like if I needed  to search for a file I could just start typing directly and the results would come. But after the update I have to click the search bar and only then can I search. Is there any way to get back the old search method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

For this 14.04 Trusty release, the developers have backported much of the "old" nautilus 3.2/3.4 functionality that was found in 12.04 & 12.10.  Many of the defaults are set for the 12.04 users so that they have a "seamless" transition to 14.04.

The feature you mentioned came in much later - probably 13.04 or 13.10.  Luckily, the developers have retained this - but you'll need to delve into the terminal to re-enable this capability through the following terminal entry

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search false
```

Naturally - if after experimenting you want to go back to the tried and trusted 12.04 capability you can reset via:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search true
```

Comment: Thanks.. I somehow missed that setting while skimming through dconf yesterday..

Comment: Is there any way to make this case sensitive?

Answer (score 3):

fossfreedom's answer is quicker than mind but this is for the users that did not know about the terminal way. You can us `dconf-editor`. First download dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then open DASH and look for dconf.

After opening go to: **org -> gnome -> nautilus -> preferences**

[image]

And here you can change the **enable-interactive-search** option. In my case I disabled the option because is more intuitive. I simply start typing and I am done with it.

As you can see from this way, it is the same thing as the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search false
```

I should also mention that you can "Double Tab" your way using the terminal line. What I mean with this is if you type:

```
gsettings
```

and then press <kbd>SPC</kbd> and then <kbd>TAB</kbd> you will be greeted with the options for **gsettings**, one of which is the **set** option used:

[image]

if we used the **set** option and press <kbd>SPC</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd> we will keep on getting all options related to what the actual configuration of that configuration database is. So you can TAB yourself to find other options when you can't remember their names.

Comment: Really thorough!

Comment: Do you know of a way to make interactive search case sensitive?